# Como configurar 2 datasources con HikariDataSource en Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuración, spring-jdbc

Buen día.

Actualmente tengo un microservicio en Spring que tiene configurados 2 datasources, que consultan información de 2 bases de datos diferentes Oracle usando de la conexión Hikari utilizando JPA con el uso de entidades que funciona de forma correcta:

1. Primer datasource

   ```
   @Configuration
   @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-apli")
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   @EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages            = "msrv.repository.apli",
                        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryRead",
                        transactionManagerRef   = "transactionManagerRead")
    public class PersistenceApliConfig extends ApliHikariConfig{

    public static final String MODEL_PACKAGE = "msrv.entity.apli";

    public PersistenceApliConfig( ApliHikariProperties hikariReadProperties) {
        super(hikariReadProperties);
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceRead")
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceRead() {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryRead( final HikariDataSource dataSourceRead ) {

        return new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {{
            setDataSource(dataSourceRead);
            setPersistenceProviderClass( HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
            setJpaProperties(JPA_READ_PROPERTIES);
        }};
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerRead( EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryRead) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryRead);
    }
    }
   ```

Clase ApliHikariConfig:

```
public class ApliHikariConfig extends HikariConfig {

    //-- aqui se almacena las propiedades de hikari del archivo [application.yml]
    protected final ApliHikariProperties hikariReadProperties;

    //-- ese es el nombre que se la a la unidad de persistencia
    protected final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "apli";

    //-- se parametrizan algunas propiedades que NO estan en el [application.yml]
    protected final Properties JPA_READ_PROPERTIES = new Properties() {{
        put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
        put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        put("hibernate.ddl-auto", "none");
        put("show-sql", "true");
    }};

    //- se parametriza el constructor de esta clase
    protected ApliHikariConfig( ApliHikariProperties hikariReadProperties) {
        this.hikariReadProperties = hikariReadProperties;
        setPoolName(this.hikariReadProperties.getPoolName());
        setMinimumIdle(this.hikariReadProperties.getMinimumIdle());
        setMaximumPoolSize(this.hikariReadProperties.getMaximumPoolSize());
        setIdleTimeout(this.hikariReadProperties.getIdleTimeout());
    }
}
```

2. Segundo datasource:

   ```
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-prod")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages            = "msrv.repository.prod",
                        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryWrite",
                        transactionManagerRef   = "transactionManagerWrite")
    public class PersistenceProdConfig extends ProdHikariConfig {

    public static final String MODEL_PACKAGE = "msrv.entity.prod";

    public PersistenceProdConfig( ProdHikariProperties hikariWriteProperties) {
        super(hikariWriteProperties);
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceWrite") 
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceWrite() {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryWrite")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryWrite( final HikariDataSource dataSourceWrite ) {
        return new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {{
            setDataSource( dataSourceWrite );
            setPersistenceProviderClass( HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            setPersistenceUnitName( PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME );
            setPackagesToScan( MODEL_PACKAGE );
            setJpaProperties ( JPA_WRITE_PROPERTIES );
        }};
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerWrite")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerWrite( EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryWrite) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryWrite);
    }
   ```

   }

Clase ProdHikariConfig

```
public class ProdHikariConfig extends HikariConfig {

    //-- aqui se almacena las propiedades de hikari del archivo [application.yml]
    protected final ProdHikariProperties hikariWriteProperties;

    //-- ese es el nombre que se la a la unidad de persistencia
    protected final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "prod";

    //-- se parametrizan algunas propiedades que NO estan en el [application.yml]
    protected final Properties JPA_WRITE_PROPERTIES = new Properties() {{
        put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
        put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        put("hibernate.ddl-auto", "none");
        put("show-sql", "true");
    }};

    //- se parametriza el constructor de esta clase
    protected ProdHikariConfig( ProdHikariProperties hikariReadProperties) {
        this.hikariWriteProperties = hikariReadProperties;
        setPoolName        ( this.hikariWriteProperties.getPoolName() );
        setMinimumIdle     ( this.hikariWriteProperties.getMinimumIdle() );
        setMaximumPoolSize ( this.hikariWriteProperties.getMaximumPoolSize() );
        setIdleTimeout     ( this.hikariWriteProperties.getIdleTimeout() );
    }
}
```

A continuación parte del archivo aplication.yml con la configuración:

```
datasource-apli:
    platform: oracle
    jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxx:1234/XXXX1
    username: xxxx
    password: 1234
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    initialize: true
    hikari:
      pool-name: ApliHikariPool
      idle-timeout: 10000
      connection-test-query: SELECT 'OK' FROM DUAL
      minimum-idle: 1
      maximum-pool-size: 1
      auto-commit: false
  datasource-prod:
    platform: oracle
    jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxx:1234/XXXX2
    username: xxxx
    password: 1234
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    initialize: true
    hikari:
      pool-name: ProdHikariPool
      idle-timeout: 10000
      connection-test-query: SELECT 'OK' FROM DUAL
      minimum-idle: 1
      maximum-pool-size: 1
      auto-commit: false
```

El PROBLEMA lo tengo cuando quiero realizar una consulta por JDBC, utilizando JDBCTemplate, de la siguiente manera: El llamado desde un component X:

```
@Component
public interface ComponentX{

    public Collection<Y> obtenerLista();
}
```

Acá la implementación del componente:

```
public class ComponentXImpl implements ComponentX {

@Autowired
private DAO DAO;

    public Collection<Y> obtenerLista(){
        return DAO.obtenerLista();
    }
}
```

Acá la clase para el llamado del JDBCTemplate

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DAOImpl implements DAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public Collection<Y> obtenerLista(){
            //sqlSentencia= Sentencia a consultar
            return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlSentencia.toString(), new XXXMapper());
        }
}
```

La clase para configurar todos los beans es la siguiente:

```
@Configuration
public class BeansConfig {
@Bean
    public DAO getDAO(){ return new DAOImpl(); }
}
```

Y al momento de levantar el microservicio, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Description:

Field DAO in msrv.component.ComponentImpl required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - DAOImpl: defined in file [....\target\classes\msrv\repository\apli\dao\DAOImpl.class]
    - getDAO: defined by method 'getDAO' in class path resource [msrv/conf/BeansConfig.class]

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Para "solucionar" este error realicé el cambio en la clase del datasource 1 (PersistenceApliConfig), añadiendo la anotación @Primary para marcarlo como datasource principal:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSourceRead")
    @Primary
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceRead() {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryRead( final HikariDataSource dataSourceRead ) {

        return new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {{
            setDataSource(dataSourceRead);
            setPersistenceProviderClass( HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
            setJpaProperties(JPA_READ_PROPERTIES);
        }};
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerRead( EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryRead) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryRead);
    }
```

Pero ahora me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-23 18:24:32,269 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryRead' defined in class path resource [com/crcc/rentafijamsrv/conf/apli/PersistenceApliConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter.getPersistenceProviderRootPackage()" because "this.delegate" is null

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter.getPersistenceProviderRootPackage()" because "this.delegate" is null
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.getPersistenceProviderRootPackage(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:168)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```